# Execute a stored procedure in connected Oracle Database on Java

Tags: java, sql, function, procedure, execute

I have a stored procedure in Oracle Database like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PSTATISTIC
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE PLACE_STATISTIC
  SET POPULARITY = 0;

  UPDATE PLACE_STATISTIC
  SET POPULARITY = POPULARITY + 1
  WHERE PLACE_ID IN (SELECT PLACE_COMMENT.PLACE_ID
                    FROM PLACE_COMMENT);

END PSTATISTIC;
```

When I called it on SQL Developer:

`EXECUTE PSTATISTIC`

It executed normally, the `PLACE_STATISTIC` table was updated

But when I tried to use it on Java:

```
String sql="EXECUTE HR.PSTATISTIC";
Statement statement=(Statement)connectionDB.createStatement();
statement.execute(sql);
```

It didn't work out on Java, citing sort of errors:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:194)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1000)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1882)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1847)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:301)
```

How can I execute my `PSTATISTIC` procedure on Java? I granted all necessary privileges

Comment: See http://www.coderanch.com/t/568116/JDBC/databases/Oracle-procedure-works-direct-SQL

Answer (score 3):

You need to use CallableStatement for executing your Stored procedure

```
String procName= "{call PSTATISTIC}";
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(procName);
cs.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

To execute a stored procedure from Java code, you need to use CallableStatement. Statement cant be used to execute Stored Proc.

```
Connection con = getConnection();
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    try {
        cs = con.prepareCall("{call EXECUTE PSTATISTIC}");
        cs.execute();


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        if (cs != null) {
            try {
                cs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```